# SQL Database not updating from a different computer

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, cpanel

I am working on a website that uses a database to take RSVPs from guests. 
When I test it out from my own computer, it works fine (that is, the database updates and shows the changes on phpmyadmin). But for some reasons, when I get someone else's computer, the database doesn't update.

I suspect it's because i'm using "localhost", but I couldn't find the host name anywhere. I have Linux Hosting with cPanel with GoDaddy.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost, "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
```

Comment: use `host name` or `server ip` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: My hosting type is cPanel so I need to use localhost. https://ca.godaddy.com/help/find-your-database-hostname-23889

Comment: i'm saying `host name` , not hosting panel. you can also use for `phpmyadmin` url where your `mysql db` is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your server IP as a mysql host and enable remote mysql for your databases through cPanel.